# Вызывать методы класса с параметрами из xml файла или массива

Tags: c#

Есть класс с методами которые могут принимать в качестве параметров строковые переменные, при этом методы разные как по количеству принимаемых параметров, так и по возвращаемому значению.
Для примера

```
obj["param1"] = xmlobj.SelectSingleNode["param2", nsmg].Atribute["param3"].Value;
obj["param4"] = class_method("param5");
```

Есть xml файл который хранит эти параметры, для простоты возьмем массив

```
string[,] param_mas = 
{
{"param1", "param2", "param3"},
{....},
}
```

Как в этом массиве можно хранить/передавать параметр, который будет отвечать за то какой метод использовать для данного набора параметров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал такое решение:

1. Сконвертировать методы, которые принимают несколько параметров в методы, которые принимают один объект-контейнер параметров.
2. Для этого объекта реализовать XML-сериализацию.

Пример:

Было:

```
static void Process(string x, int y)
{
    if (x.CompareTo(y.ToString()) > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Yes");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No");
}

Process("Value", 5);
```

Стало:

```
public class ProcessParameters
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

static void Process(ProcessParameters p)
{
    if (p.X.CompareTo(p.Y.ToString()) > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Yes");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No");
}

var s = "<ProcessParameters X=\"Value\" Y=\"5\"/>";
using (var reader = new StringReader(s))
{
    var pp = (ProcessParameters)new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessParameters))
                                        .Deserialize(reader);
    Process(pp);
}
```

---

С другой стороны, если вам нужно такое, может быть вам *на самом деле* нужен WCF?

Comment: Не могу придумать как разграничить что первый набор параметров должен использовать метод `class_method1`, а второй например `class_method2`, а третий другой метод.

Comment: @e1s: Ну, например задавайте тип (имя?) метода в параметрах.

Comment: Это понятно, но как его потом вызвать? там же просто строка хранится. А насчет wcf это и так asp service

Comment: @e1s: Ну а чем switch по имени не подходит?

Comment: Думал есть что то более "элегантное"

Comment: @e1s: Мне более элегантное не пришло в голову :-(